# What's the correct format of a forward zone in bind

Tags: dns, bind

can someone please enlighten me in setting up the correct format of forward zone.

```
$TTL    604800
foo.com.        IN      SOA     foo.com. admin.foo.com. (
                                      2         ; Serial
                                 604800         ; Refresh
                                  86400         ; Retry
                                2419200         ; Expire
                                 604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

foo.com.        IN      A       dns.foo.com.

www             IN      A       192.168.1.54
dns             IN      A       192.168.1.5
```

this part

```
foo.com.        IN      A       dns.foo.com.
```

should i replace the `dns` with my dns server hostname? cause ive seen others use `ns1` or `dns`?

so if my dns hostname is `test`, id be using `test.foo.com.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct line should be:

```
foo.com.        IN      NS       dns.foo.com.
```

The  DNS servers should be registered in a NS type record. The name is up to you. If your DNS hostname is "test", write:

```
foo.com.        IN      NS       test.foo.com.
```

You'll also need a A type record saying who is "test":

```
test            IN      A        192.168.X.X
```